# use Batch File to find a file in another server

Tags: batch-file

I am try to find a file in another server with .bat.
But, this folder is only shared to my account, not everyone.

```
@ECHO OFF
IF EXIST "\\server\NewFolder\folder.txt" (
ECHO "YES"
) ELSE (
ECHO "NO"
)
```

This is works , but only with "everyone shared".

There is another way or something.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use NET USE to access UNC's in command prompt. You have to use a `net use "\\server\path"`

Comment: I just prove the connection. with NET USE

Answer (score 0):

Well, I did a Mapping Network Drive from another server. that's easy way to resolve it.